# chrome selection text to keep formatting

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, formatting, selection

I have a context menu, so when you selection some text from a page they can send to my extension. I am using

```
var child1 = chrome.contextMenus.create(
    {"title": "Send To Box" , contexts:["selection"], "parentId": id, "id":"box", "contexts":[context], "onclick": sendToMyBox});
```

And in my sendToMyBox

```
function sendToMyBox(info, tab) 
{
  if (info.menuItemId == "box")
  {
    mainData = info.selectionText;
  }
}
```

So the issue is selectionText is missing all the formatting. What ever selected its coming as a single line text, is there anyway I can get the current format from the selected. Basically I want to keep all the new lines tabs, etc...

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe you can get the html element first (you can achieve that by register a mouse event, then get event.target), then use

```
element.innerHTML
```

to get the rich text.

Comment: Sorry for late comment, but I am not really sure how to implement that in my function, any docs ?

Comment: never mind I got it working and thanks a lot for the proper hint.